# How to get a submit button to redirect to home page after calling the javascript code to check the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi guys so im trying to get this form thingo to work and so far (that i've checked) I cant seem to redirect my form back to the home page. I've tried the action="homepage" but it redirects it straight away without calling on the javascript at all. Heres the Javascript.

```
                                    function checkScript() {
                var nfilter = /^\S\D+$/;
                var fname = document.signup.fname;
                var lname = document.signup.lname;
                var uname = document.signup.uname;
                var password = document.signup.pass;
                var efilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})$/;
                var email = document.getElementById("email").value;


                for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    box = document.signup.elements[i];
                    if(!box.value) {
                        alert("You haven't provided  your " + box.id + "!");
                        box.focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }               

                if (!nfilter.test(fname.value)) {
                    alert("Please provide a valid first name!");
                    fname.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if(!nfilter.test(lname.value)) {
                    alert("Please provide a valid last name!");
                    lname.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if(!efilter.test(email)) {
                    alert("Please provide a valid email! Not " + email);
                    email.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }   `
```

and heres the Html:

```
                    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="first name"> 
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="last name"> <br /> <br/>
        Username: <input type="text" name="uname" id="user name"> <br/> <br/>
        Password: <input type="text" name="pass" id="password"> <br/> <br/>

        Gender: <select name = "gender" id="gender">
            <option value="" selected disabled> Please select an option...</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            <option value="not provided">Do not wish to provide</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> <br /> <br/> 

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="button" name="Reset" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset()">
    </form> `
```

(thats just the form so i have checked all my 's and stuff are closed which they are)

```
           btw if the top bit doesnt show its says
```

`<form name="signup" onsubmit="return checkScript()">`

Comment: you can do that with the action attribute. `<form  name="signup" onsubmit="return checkScript()" action="index.php">`

Comment: What happens if you just do it like this? onsubmit="return false"

Comment: Michael Kunst when i tried your idea it goes straight to the index.php without running the Javascript for some unknown reason.

Comment: remove the `return` call.

Answer (score 0):

You run your `checkScript()` function on form submit. Why not simply add the redirect line in the function itself, on the happy path? For example, this...

```
window.location.replace('YOUR REDIRECT URL');
```

... will do the trick.

(Note, I use `window.location.replace` rather than `window.location.href` because the former is effectively akin to a redirect, whereas the latter is the programmatic equivalent of clicking on a link).

Comment: Ohh so are you saying to have the redirection in the Javascript code?

Comment: @user3500310 Yes. It's the obvious place to put it (only if the `checkScript` validation runs successfully of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the page after your valdiation process is finished using

```
location.href = "homepage";
```

The `checkScript()` should then look like below:

```
function checkScript() {
  var nfilter = /^\S\D+$/;
  var fname = document.signup.fname;
  var lname = document.signup.lname;
  var uname = document.signup.uname;
  var password = document.signup.pass;
  var efilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})$/;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    box = document.signup.elements[i];
    if(!box.value) {
      alert("You haven't provided  your " + box.id + "!");
      box.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (!nfilter.test(fname.value)) {
    alert("Please provide a valid first name!");
    fname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!nfilter.test(lname.value)) {
    alert("Please provide a valid last name!");
    lname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!efilter.test(email)) {
    alert("Please provide a valid email! Not " + email);
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  location.href="homepage";
  return true;
}
```

And change the from action attribute to `javascript:checkScript();` so that the form header look as follows:

```
<form name="signup" action="javascript:checkScript();">
```

Comment: Thank you! However when i used your action="javascript:checkScript();" Its trying to redirect it to the javascript?

Comment: You still can opt for your solution which I find ligible and you can use the `onsubmit` attribute.